# Separate variables in equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I need to know is there a way to separate the desired variables in the equation at one side of the equality. For instance, the following equation

```
(E^(-Subscript[λ, 0]*Subscript[T, 1]) (Subscript[λ, 0]*Subscript[T, 1])^x)/x!*
(E^(-Subscript[λ, 0]*Subscript[T, 2]) (Subscript[λ, 0]*Subscript[T, 2])^y)/y!*
(E^(-(Subscript[λ, 0] + Subscript[λ, 0])*Subscript[T, 3]) 
    ((Subscript[λ, 0] + Subscript[λ, 0])*Subscript[T, 3])^z)/z! = 
(E^(-Subscript[λ, 1]*Subscript[T, 1]) (Subscript[λ, 1]*Subscript[T, 1])^x)/x!*
(E^(-Subscript[λ, 1]*Subscript[T, 2]) (Subscript[λ, 1]*Subscript[T, 2])^y)/y!*
(E^(-(Subscript[λ, 1] + Subscript[λ, 1])*Subscript[T, 3]) 
    ((Subscript[λ, 1] + Subscript[λ, 1])*Subscript[T, 3])^z)/z!
```

can be written as

```
x + y + z = ((Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 0])*Subscript[T, 1] + 
    (Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 0])*Subscript[T, 2] + 
    2*(Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 0]) Subscript[T, 3])/
    Log[Subscript[λ, 1]/Subscript[λ, 0]]
```

How to perform the above separation of variables in mathematica?

It could be done in one variable, but how to separate when we have more than one variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single command that accomplishes the simplification desired.  However, a string of commands can accomplish it.  To begin, cast the two equations into the proper syntax by replacing `=` by `==`.  Then, name the first equation `f` for convenience, `Divide` one side of the equation by the other, take the `Log` of the result, `FullSimplify`, and divide by the `Log` term.

```
Collect[FullSimplify[Log[Divide @@ f], x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && 
  Subscript[T, 1] > 0 && Subscript[T, 2] > 0 && Subscript[T, 3] > 0 && 
  Subscript[λ, 0] > 0 && Subscript[λ, 1] > 0]
  / Log[Subscript[λ, 0]/Subscript[λ, 1]], x + y + z]

(* x + y + z - ((Subscript[T, 1] + Subscript[T, 2] + 
       2 Subscript[T, 3]) (Subscript[λ, 0] - Subscript[λ, 1]))/
       Log[Subscript[λ, 0]/Subscript[λ, 1]] *)
```

Specifying that the variables are positive is necessary so that Mathematica does not have issues with branch cuts.  (Also, as noted by [Jack LaVigne](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/10917/jack-lavigne), "the division step created an equation with 1 on one side of the equality and then the logarithm operation converted it to zero".)

Another approach is to `Subtract` the `Log` of each side of `f`, `FullSimplify`, and `Solve` for `x + y +z`, which gives the same result as before.

```
Solve[(FullSimplify[Subtract @@ (Log[List @@ f]), x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && 
  Subscript[T, 1] > 0 && Subscript[T, 2] > 0 && Subscript[T, 3] > 0 && 
  Subscript[λ, 0] > 0 && Subscript[λ, 1] > 0] /. x + y + z -> w) == 0, w][[1, 1]] 
  /. w -> x + y + z /. Rule -> Equal
```

Incidentally, I do not recommend using `Subscript` variables in Mathematica calculations.  They may look good but sometimes cause needless problems.